Why dont I get all the activity templates in my latest version of Android Studio?
I am using windows 10. Android studio Koala latest release. Have used Hedgehog and Chipmunk versions. The Chipmunk version gave google maps and settings activity template while creating new project. For Hedgehog these activity templates disappeared after 3 projects. Now when I have installed Koala it shows only some templates. I need the settings template but can't find it in koala and Hedgehog. Is it just me or everyone having this problem. And if its only at my end how do I get the template setting activity.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Koala and Hedgehog versions but no change. Problem persists


It looks like they started removing some templates since Android Studio Flamingo and there has been an open issue to ask for the possibility to "install" them at your own discretion like plugins.
